# Accidentally deleted root privileges to my AWS user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am totally newbie with AWS, my first project with it.

I was trying to deploy my Django app with Elastic Beanstalk, using CodeCommit, following a tutorial. I was getting an error while trying to connect to the repo. Searching around that error, I got to the conclusion that I probably needed to enable AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess policy for my user. However, before doing that I 'detached' the first (and I think the only) policy that I had attached to my account. I think it was 'AdministratorAccess' or something similar (the first option in a large policies list). I just wanted to fit my user to the tasks that would be required and I interpreted that having admin privileges is not safe. Later I read that I should have created a new user with no root privileges, and work with that new user on a daily basis. I promise I will do that the next time.

So I am locked right now. **I have just one user with privileges for doing absolutely nothing.** I cannot even purchase development support (29$/month), to solve this situation... I don't know what to do. I could forget that account and open a new one, but I think there must be something I could do.

I tried searching for almost 2 hours, but I couldn't find anything that could work for me. I repeat that I am completely newbie on AWS and probably I didn't use the correct words in my searching process.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally solved. I explain.

While following the tutorial, I signed up AWS and created a user called 'username' for the deployment process in Elastic Beanstalk. I thought the user I created following the tutorial was my current user in AWS, but (fortunately) it wasn't.

I logged in with the 'username' user and detached the AdministratorAccess policy from that user, so the user has privileges to do nothing.

After some more reading, I found that if you login to AWS with your email (not the 'username'), you log as the root user. That allowed me to attach the correct policies to the user.

Here the difference between IAM users and root user:

From IAM users [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html):

> An IAM user with administrator permissions is not the same thing as the AWS account root user.

From root users [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html):

> When you first create an Amazon Web Services (AWS) account, you begin with a single sign-in identity that has complete access to all AWS services and resources in the account. This identity is called the AWS account root user and is accessed by signing in with the email address and password that you used to create the account.

I have a lot to learn around AWS, but I hope my story helps somebody...